# How to access box-and-whisker specifications from custom ChartElementFunction?

Tags: plotting, customization, charts

I am creating a custom `ChartElementFunction` for `BoxWhiskerChart`. I would like to access the box-and-whisker specifications from the second parameter of `BoxWhiskerChart` to use in the custom function; just as the built-in element functions.  Minimal custom element function:

```
ClearAll[cef];
cef[boundingBox_, data_, meta_] :=
 Module[{qt = Quantile[data, {0, 0.25, .5, 0.75, 1}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}],
         h = First@Differences@boundingBox[[2]],
         m = Mean@boundingBox[[2]]},
  {
   {Thickness[.005], CapForm["Butt"], Blue,
    Line[{
     {qt[[1]], m - .1 h}, 
     {qt[[1]], m + .1 h}}]},
   {Thickness[.005], CapForm["Butt"], Magenta,
    Line[{
     {qt[[5]], m - .1 h}, 
     {qt[[5]], m + .1 h}}]}
   }
  ]
```

Minimal example where the fences are drawn different colours. The box-and-whisker `"Fences"` specification says to draw them 80% of the height of the box-whisker. However, I don't have access to this and have to hard-code a value (in this case 20% of the height).  The regular element function is added to cut down on the size of the post.

```
SeedRandom[953];
data = RandomVariate[ChiSquareDistribution[5], 100];
BoxWhiskerChart[data, {"Basic", {"Fences", .8, None}}, 
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartElementFunction -> ({cef[##], ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker"][##]} &)]
```

[image]

Can the second parameter box-and-whisker specifications be accessed in a custom `ChartElementFunction` as they are in the built-in ones? I would prefer not to move the specifications into a parameter of the custom function.

Comment: @JasonB Nope. Those are the normal arguments to the chart element function. I'm looking to access the `{"Basic", {"Fences", .8, None}}` argument to `BoxWhiskerChart` just as `ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker"]` accesses it and knows to use `None` as the style of the fences (which is why there are no 80% height fences in the chart).

Comment: yeah I figured that out as soon as I commented, deleted.  Do you have the `Spelunking` package installed?  It looks like you can get an understanding for the internals via ``Spelunk[Charting`iBoxWhiskerChart]``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspecting the code for the function `` System`BarFunctionDump`boxplot ``, it looks like you can access the fence specs -- (.8, None) in your example -- using `` Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Fence"] `` inside your `cef`.

More generally, all box and whiskers specifications, `"Color",  "BarOrigin", "Outliers", "BoxRange"` etc.,  can be accessed using `` Charting`ChartStyleInformation ``. We can get all properties that can be accessed using `` Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Properties"] ``.

```
ClearAll[cef];
cef[box_, data_, meta___] := Module[
 {qt = Quantile[data, {0, 0.25, .5, 0.75, 1}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
  h = First @ Differences@box[[2]], 
  m = Mean @ box[[2]]}, 
 {{Opacity[.3, Gray], Rectangle @@ 
    Transpose[Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"]]}, 
  {Thickness[.005], CapForm["Butt"], Blue, 
   Print /@ (PromptForm[#, Charting`ChartStyleInformation[#]] & /@ 
      Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Properties"]); 
   Line[{{qt[[1]], m - .1 h}, {qt[[1]], m + .1 h}}]}, 
  {Thickness[.005], CapForm["Butt"], Magenta, 
   Line[{{qt[[5]], m - .1 h}, {qt[[5]], m + .1 h}}]}}]
```

Using a different input data with several far outliers:

```
SeedRandom[777];
data = RandomVariate[ParetoDistribution[3, 9], 100];

BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
  {"Basic", 
   {"Fences", .8, None}, 
   {"Outliers", "A", Green}, 
   {"FarOutliers", "B", Red}}, 
  BarOrigin -> Left, 
  ChartElementFunction -> ({ChartElementData["BoxWhisker"][##], cef[##]} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice find. (1+) Waiting a bit for the accept as is the custom.

Comment: Did you find anything for `"FarOutliers"`?

Comment: @Edmund, when `"Outliers"` and/or `"FarOutliers"` are specified ``Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Outliers"]`` gives a two-element list the second of which is the spec for `"FarOutliers"`.