# Tuning BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: charts

I have a large set of experimental data points (`n`) and I want perform some statistics on them. Particularly instead of showing all data points using `ListPlot` I want to narrow this set into several smaller intervals with defined width (`m`) and show some statistical information characterizing data in these intervals. To start with I tried to do it with `BoxWhiskerChart`. Below is an example code I wrote:

```
m = 10000;
n = 5;
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], m];
BoxWhiskerChart[Table[data[[IntegerPart[m/n]*(i-1)+1;;IntegerPart[m/n]*i]],{i,n}], 
  ChartLabels->Table[ToString[i],{i,n}]]
```

It returned me the a nice Box-Whisker chart of my data. However, I believe, by default (please correct me if I am wrong) it shows median for the middle of the box, first and third quartiles for the top and bottom of the box, min and max values for whiskers.

Is it possible to tune this so that it will show the mean (average) for the middle of the box and chosen confidence bands or standard error for whiskers?

Another question: is it possible to color boxes for different intervals differently?

Comment: related q/a: [How to access box-and-whisker specifications from custom ChartElementFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121462/125)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**  We can use the `"BoxRange"` sub-option of `Method` combined with the option `"IQRCoefficient"` in `ChartElementDataFunction` to get the boxes and fences placed at `x StandardDeviation` distance below and above the `Mean` without having to use a custom `ChartElementFunction`.

The elements of `BoxWhiskerChart` are determined by the 5 quantiles of the data (namely, `Quantile[data, {0,.25, .5, .75, 1}]`). The location of the fences are controlled by the option `IQRCoefficient` that can be specified in the setting of the option `ChartElementFunction` as in

```
ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker", "IQRCoefficient" -> iqr]
```

so that the lower fence is placed at `Quartile[data][[1]] - iqr InterquartileRange[data]` and the upper fence at  `Quartile[data][[3]] + iqr InterquartileRange[data]`.

One way to base the `BoxWhiskerChart` elements on the `Mean` and `StandardDeviation` (rather than on quantiles) is to use the sub-option `"BoxRange"` in the `Method` option of `BoxWhiskerChart`. This can be done defining

```
boxRange = Through[{Min, Mean[#] - StandardDeviation[#] &, Mean, 
      Mean[#] + StandardDeviation[#] &, Max}@#] &;
```

and using it as in

```
Method -> {"BoxRange" -> boxRange}
```

Combined with the option

```
ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker", "IQRCoefficient" -> 1/2]
```

we will get a box defined by `Mean - StandardDeviation` and `Mean + StandardDeviation` (as opposed to a box defined by the first and third quartiles) and fences at 2 `StandardDeviation` below and above the `Mean`.

**Example:**

```
bwcdata = Table[data[[IntegerPart[m/n]*(i - 1) + 1 ;;  IntegerPart[m/n]*i]], {i, n}];

options = {{{"MedianMarker", 1, None}, {"Outliers", Green}, 
     {"MeanMarker", 1, Directive[Thickness[.01], CapForm["Butt"], Red]},
     {"Fences", 1, Directive[Thickness[.01], Purple]}, 
     {"Whiskers",  Directive[Thickness[.025], CapForm["Butt"], Orange]}}, 
   ChartLabels -> Table[ToString[i], {i, n}], ChartStyle -> 1, 
   ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker", "IQRCoefficient" -> 1/2],
   Method -> {"BoxRange" -> boxRange}};

BoxWhiskerChart[bwcdata, ## & @@ options]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
BoxWhiskerChart[#, ## & @@ options, ImageSize -> 200, 
    GridLines -> {None, boxRange@#}] & /@ bwcdata // Row
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

You can use the second argument of `BoxWhiskerChart` to show the `MeanMarker` instead of the default `MedianMarker`.

```
BoxWhiskerChart[Table[data[[IntegerPart[m/n]*(i - 1) + 1 ;; IntegerPart[m/n]*i]], {i, n}], 
 {{"MedianMarker", None}, {"MeanMarker", 1, White}}, 
 ChartLabels -> Table[ToString[i], {i, n}], ChartStyle -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think OP is asking to customize the whisker limits as well.  Can this be done in `BoxWhiskerChart`?

Comment: Thank you @jjc385. I think/hope the update handles the positioning of the boxes and the fences.

Answer (score 7):

As @kglr shows, one can use the Method option of [`BoxWhiskerChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart) to control the location of the fences. On the other hand, it is also possible to control the appearance of the chart by using a custom [`ChartElementFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction). For example:

```
custom[{{l_,r_}, {b_, t_}}, values_, _] := Module[{mean, q25, q75, lf, uf, mid, sl, sr},
    mid = (l+r)/2;
    {sl, sr} = mid+{-1,1}(r-l)/4;
    mean = Mean[values];
    {lf, q25, q75, uf} = Quantile[values, {.05,.25,.75,.95}];
    {
        (* whiskers *)
        Line[{{mid,lf},{mid,uf}}],

        (* upper fence *)
        Line[{{sl,uf},{sr,uf}}],

        (* lower fence *)
        Line[{{sl,lf},{sr,lf}}],

        (* box *)
        FaceForm[Cyan], Rectangle[{l,q25},{r,q75}],

        (* mean *)
        Line[{{l,mean},{r,mean}}]
    }
]
```

And here is how it looks:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],100];

BoxWhiskerChart[data, ChartElementFunction->custom]
```

[image]